# Users group has Read & Execute access to C:\Windows file & Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Just wonder is it the systems behavior for window server 2008 R2 Standard to allow users group has Read & Execute access to C:\Windows file & Microsoft SQL Server?

I tried to modified the permission for user groups in both the files to Read only, but the check box is grey out.

Just wonder anyone experience this?

I cannot post image because reputation is too low

Thanks

Comment: "_I cannot post image because reputation is too low_" You can post a link to the image and then someone with more reputation will edit to post the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Applications that are running under an account in that group may need to access the libraries or executables in the SQL server installation folder.

The C:\Windows folder also contains most of the Windows components that all user accounts need access to all the time, e.g. cmd.exe, explorer.exe, etc.

I strongly suggest not adjusting the default permissions of the operating system's folders as this can compromise the functionality of the system.